# Converting arrays of strings to datetime

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops

I have a string im converting to datetime format, which works just fine:

```
$d = 'hourly-12-18-2017-20-15-00' -split '-'
```

Gets me:

```
hourly
12
18
2017
20
15
00
```

Converting it to datetime

```
$i = Get-Date -Day $d[2] -Month $d[1] -Year $d[3] -Hour $d[4] -Minute $d[5] -Second $d[6]
```

Gets me:

```
18. december 2017 20:15:00
```

Which is what i expect and it works.

Now in reality this is a list of strings so im trying to loop thru it.
The actual list after conversion:

```
 hourly
 12
 28
 2017
 10
 15
 00
 hourly
 12
 28
 2017
 11
 15
 02
```

And so on..

Im trying to write these out formatted:

```
foreach ($i in $d) {

$i = @(Get-Date -Day $d[2] -Month $d[1] -Year $d[3] -Hour $d[4] -Minute $d[5] -Second $d[6])
$i
}
```

Gets me:

```
18. december 2017 20:15:00
```

Instead if the whole list. Only last entry is written out.

I also tried with same result:

```
$d | ForEach-Object {
$i = @(Get-Date -Day $d[2] -Month $d[1] -Year $d[3] -Hour $d[4] -Minute $d[5] -Second $d[6])
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: are you getting the list of date in this format - 'hourly-12-28-2017-10-15-00','hourly-12-28-2017-11-15-02' and then you are converting it to the list which you posted.

Comment: Correct. I am doing the conversion from hourly-12-28-2017-10-15-00 to the split list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't split, just remove `hourly-`.

```
$D = 'hourly-12-28-2017-10-15-00','hourly-12-28-2017-11-15-02'
$D -replace 'hourly-' | foreach {
    [datetime]::ParseExact($_, "MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss", $null)
}

Thursday, December 28, 2017 10:15:00 AM
Thursday, December 28, 2017 11:15:02 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

As [another answer has already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48006980/712649), you don't actually need to `-split` each individual string in the first place, you can just parse the date from the original string.

To solve the problem of partitioning your large string array into smaller chunks each corresponding to a date, you could do something like:

```
$strings = @('hourly', '12', '28', '2017', '10', '15', '00', 'hourly', '12', '28', '2017', '11', '15', '02')
do{
    $ds = @{}
    $null,$ds['Month'],$ds['Day'],$ds['Year'],$ds['Hour'],$ds['Minute'],$ds['Second'],$strings = $strings
    Get-Date @ds
} while($strings)
```

on each iteration, the `hourly` string will be swallowed by `$null`, the next 6 strings (the datetime components), will populate a hashtable, and (any) remaining strings will be assigned back to `$strings`.

Finally, `Get-Date @ds` will create the new DateTime object based on the parameter values in the hashtable